# Deployment failure Jboss 4.2.0

Tags: linux, jboss, locking, workspace, myeclipse

Deployment failure on JBoss 4.x  Could not copy all resources to E:\jboss-4.2.0.GA\server\default\deploy\etc.war.If a file is locked, you can wait until the lock   times out to redeploy, or stop the server and redeploy,or manually remove the deployment at E:\jboss-4.2.0.GA\server\default\deploy\etc.war.how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to stop the server, simple steps are:

```
Stop the server, redeploy the WAR and start the server.
```

Comment: already tried ..not working ... i have cleaned the porject also